# CSS: make element overlay every other element

Tags: html, css

I am making dropdown menu for my main menu, there is username where user clicks and then it shows the content (dropdown menu), This was made by checkbox type input for the button.

Unfortunately, menu doesn't seem to show at all, and disappears at the end of the menu.

Menu:

HTML:

```
    <div class="profilebar">
        <div class="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="droptoggle" class="toggled">
            <label for="droptoggle" class="profilename" style="cursor: pointer;">{{ username }}<span class="caret">&blacktriangledown;</span></label>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="sub-menu">
                    <a href="/">Link1</a> 
                    <a href="/">Link2</a>
                    <a href="/">Link3</a>
                    <a href-"/">Link4t</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <img class="profilepicture" src="url here"></img>
        <p class="balance" style="text-decoration:none">${{ balance }}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.profilebar {
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 7%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  min-width: 70px;
}
.profilename {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 0.5%;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.caret {
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 10px;
  min-width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu + a:hover {
  background-color: #C90205
}
.toggled {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.profilepicture {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1.2%;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}
.balance {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2.3%;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #C90205;
  margin-left: 44.5%;
}
.toggled:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfa67m3u/3/embedded/result/) ( Don't look at image, it is placeholder anyway ).

---

So what can the problem be? i have tried z-index on positioned elements which didn't seem to work out, how can i make dropdown menu overlay every other element so it can be fully seen?

Comment: by overlooking at your code dropdown menu is hidden becoz your parent .menu has overflow:hidden remove that

Comment: try z-index: 99 on .dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu has `overflow: hidden`, so it will hide when going beyond the content, removing the `overflow: hidden` from the `menu` class shows the dropdown menu.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yfa67m3u/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.profilebar {
/*   float: right;
  width: 150px;
  height: 7%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 1.5%;
  min-width: 70px; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.5%;
  right: 1.5%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 7%;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.profilename {
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  width: 0.5%;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.caret {
  margin-left: 3.5%;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-left: 4%;
}

.dropdown label {
  color: #333;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #333;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu + a:hover {
  background-color: #C90205
}
.toggled {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}
.profilepicture {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 1.2%;
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 1.5px;
}
.balance {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2.3%;
  color: red;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: #C90205;
  margin-left: 44.5%;
}
.toggled:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="profilebar">
        <div class="dropdown" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input type="checkbox" id="droptoggle" class="toggled">
            <label for="droptoggle" class="profilename" style="cursor: pointer;">USERNAME<span class="caret">&blacktriangledown;</span></label>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li class="sub-menu">
                    <a href="/">Link1</a> 
                    <a href="/">Link2</a>
                    <a href="/">Link3</a>
                    <a href="/">Link4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <img class="profilepicture" src="url here"></img>
        <p class="balance" style="text-decoration:none">BALANCE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```